# Substituting value of mysql function stored in string in resultset statement using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In Java I have a defined a string named year:

```
  String year="year(now())-1"
```

Now I want the value of this string to be subsituted below using `where like` clause:

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select abc from table where year like '"+year+"' " )
```

But using above statement I get no result.
Can anyone please tell where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minus 1 year

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

So you can use

```
String year="DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)"
```

Final:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select abc from table where year = "+year+"");
```

Comment: but still i am getting no output

Comment: Are you sure your query will return result? Try run "select year from abc" to verify there is year = 2011

Comment: yes it worked with = operator but i want implement using like operator because i have condition in which i want to select all year.For selecting all values of year i have to use LIKE '%%' which cannot be use in = operator

Comment: LIKE operator is for string, you should use IN operator. Please indicate how you get years from user.

Comment: but using IN operator i cannot get all values as i need to specify the in it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the comparison operator = instead of like? Also, have you checked the input parameter in relation to the data?  Log the query and see what is actually being generated.

Comment: yes i tried it but its not working. but i want to use it using like

Answer (score 0):

try using % in you where with like:

`stmt.executeQuery("select abc from table where year like '%"+year+"%' " )`

Comment: what is the value of `year` in your table and what is in the `year` variable?

Comment: year is basically a INT variable having values such as 2011,2001 etc

Answer (score 0):

include % in like...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select abc from table where year like '%"+year+"%' " )
```